# When model changes, animate between old value and new value in Angular2

Tags: angular

I have got a counter that is bound to view. Whenever the counter/model changes, the view updates as expected.

However, I would like the old value to go up and down. Am not looking for fading in/out between old and new values. I am looking for counter to go up/down, one figure at a time, till the new figure is reached.

Comment: Did you check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html ?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a component for that. That's the Angular way of doing it.

There are probably some third party libraries for that, but creating your own counter component is fairly easy. Here's one I created just now:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'counter'
  template: `<span>{{displayValue}}</span>`
})
export class Counter {
  @Input() value: number;
  private displayValue: number = 0;
  private interval;

  ngOnChanges(changes: {[propertyName: string]: SimpleChange}) {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    let change = changes.value;
    if (change) {
      let target:number = parseInt(change.currentValue) || 0;
      let step = target < this.displayValue ? -1 : 1;
      this.interval = setInterval(() => {
        if (this.displayValue !== target) {
          this.displayValue += step;
        }
        else {
          clearInterval(this.interval);
        }
      }, 100);
    }
  }
}
```

You can see a live demo of it [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/rWNOJu2zTX2MUQxS1MnF?p=preview).